# How to map a value in an array to a property

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to parse a json and get hold of value inside an array -

```
 {
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
          "name": [
            {
              "family": "Doe",
              "given": "Jon",
              "middle": "Smith",
              "use": "Commercial"
            }
          ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is my pojo

```
private String fstNm;

 public String getFstNm() { return fstNm; }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setFstNm(Map<String,Object>name) {
        this.fstNm = (String) name.get("given");

    }
```

But for some reason it is not working and i am getting `Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token`

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: is this exactly the JSON you want to parse? it should have surrounding brackets, e.g. `{}`,  to be valid JSON...

Comment: Yes it is JSON i just updated my question

Comment: the value of your JSON property `name` is an array. please try to remove both square brackets `[]` from your JSON to verify if it works then...

Comment: @TommyBrettschneider based on the below answer i realized that i have one more array at root level. May i know how do i effectively write a method that would simply return name. I have tried to post an answer which is not really helping me. It is returning name as a list which i don't want and then fstNm is empty. All i want is fstNm to be returned with a value form a field "given"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your JSON, the name is actually a List, so you should map:

```
@JsonProperty("name")
public void setFstNm(List<Map<String, Object>> name) {
    this.fstNm = (String) name.get(0).get("given");
}
```

This is getting the property 'given' from the first position of the array. Of course, you need to check before if the list is empty or not and if you really want the first one.

[UPDATED]

For the new JSON specified above, another way to parse is:

```
@JsonProperty("hits")
public void setFstNm(Map<String, List<Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>>> hits) {
    this.fstNm = (String) hits.get("hits").get(0).get("name").get(0).get("given");
}
```

Or, if you are parsing using the ObjectMapper, you can easy read:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(<<JSON>>);
String givenName = jsonNode.get("hits").get("hits").get(0)
    .get("name").get(0).get("given").asText();
```

Comment: your answer made me realize that i have one more array at root level. I have tried to post the modification above but this is going to return entire name array and at the same time fstNm would be empty. May i know how to effectively create a method that would simply return the name ?

Comment: @JonAbraham can you confirm the JSON is correct now? It looks the path now would be: hits -> hits[0] -> name[0] -> given

Comment: yes it is the correct JSON now and the path would be hits--->hits[0]--->name[0]---->given

Answer (score 0):

```
private String fstNm;

  private List<Map<String,Object>> name;

public String getFstNm() { return fstNm; }

 @JsonProperty("hits")
    public void setFstNm(List<Map<String, Object>> hits) {

        name = (List) hits.get(0).get("name");

        this.fstNm= (String) name.get(0).get("given");
        

    }
```